# Collapse some programs on taskbar but not all

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I'm just looking to un-group or un-collapse one program I use and leave the rest to grou on the taskbar, without having to download an external application, is there a way to modify a setting in W7 to allow me to pick what programs to group and what not to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible without using a third-party application, according to this [thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/28596-possible-ungroup-only-specific-programs.html).  If you are OK with using a third party application, you can try [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker).